# Why my mysql DISTINCT doesn't work?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Why the two query below return duplicate member_id and not the third?

I need the second query to work with distinct.  Anytime i run a **GROUP BY**, this query is incredibly slow and the resultset doesn't return the same value as distinct (the value is wrong).

```
SELECT member_id, id 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY created_at desc ) as u 
LIMIT 5

+-----------+--------+
| member_id | id     |
+-----------+--------+
|     11333 | 313095 |
|    141831 | 313094 |
|    141831 | 313093 |
|     12013 | 313092 |
|     60821 | 313091 |
+-----------+--------+
```

---

```
SELECT distinct member_id, id 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY created_at desc ) as u 
LIMIT 5

+-----------+--------+
| member_id | id     |
+-----------+--------+
|     11333 | 313095 |
|    141831 | 313094 |
|    141831 | 313093 |
|     12013 | 313092 |
|     60821 | 313091 |
+-----------+--------+
```

---

```
  SELECT distinct member_id
    FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY created_at desc ) as u 
    LIMIT 5

+-----------+
| member_id |
+-----------+
|     11333 |
|    141831 |
|     12013 |
|     60821 |
|     64980 |
+-----------+
```

my table sample

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `s_FI_1` (`member_id`),
  KEY `s_FI_2` (`s_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=313096 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a syntax similar to this?
 SELECT distinct member_id
  FROM table1 
  ORDER BY created_at desc
  LIMIT 5

Comment: the parenthesis give priority to the orderby, an i need to retrieve also the id column.

Comment: to be clear i need to retrieve {member_id, id} which is the latest 5 entry and each row has to have the {member_id} unique.

Comment: The subquery executes first, which is why there's "priority to the ORDER BY".  But Eineki is correct - what you posted is unnecessary and redundant, it can be performed in the single query Eineki provided.

Comment: thank you for the advice, but that's not the point ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works, its dirty (no index, no key, temporary table...) but it works,

```
SELECT member_id,id 
FROM ( SELECT member_id,id, created_at FROM table1 ORDER BY created_at desc ) as u 
group by member_id ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 18):

`DISTINCT` is a keyword you can only apply on the whole `SELECT`, and not on a single field. It ensures the database doesn't return two identical rows. This is why your second query with `DISTINCT` returns only one time each `member_id` while your first returns it twice. In its result set, each row is indeed unique, even though you can get several times the same `member_id`.

Comment: I'll upvote instead - should I still comment :) - for a point of relevance, zneak's answer is spot on.

Comment: You could do this:
SELECT member_id, id FROM table1 
WHERE member_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT member_id FROM table1)

All you need to add to that are your limits

Comment: thorkia's methods isn't correct.... in leads to duplications

Answer (score 1):

In first query, there is no distinct keyword. In 2nd query it is selecting distinct rows. not distinct member id. In the third query, there is only member id, so it is selecting the distinct member ids

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT distinct member_id, id 
>   FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY created_at desc ) as u 
>   LIMIT 5

`member_id` is not unique. So that makes the query show more rows...

Comment: Whoops, meant member_id. Corrected. But even if member_id where a primary key too, then Table1 could be a view bringing both fields together ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_table1_createdat ON table1 (created_at);
CREATE INDEX ix_table1_memberid_createdat ON table1 (member_id, created_at);
```

and use this query:

```
SELECT  t1i.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT member_id
        FROM    table1 tdi
        ORDER BY
                created_at DESC
        LIMIT 5
        ) t1d
JOIN    table1 t1i
ON      t1i.id =
        (
        SELECT  t1o.id
        FROM    table1 t1o
        WHERE   t1o.member_id = t1d.member_id
        ORDER BY
                t1o.member_id DESC, t1o.created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```