# How to display data based on post date similar to a timeline using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

please help me I'm really in a great problem. I want to display posts(articles) under their respective posting date.

For example,

```
NOVEMBER 05
* Post 1
* Post 2
* Post 3

NOVEMBER 04
* Post 1
* Post 2
```

I have written a PHP code but it's repeating dates and values twice, like:

```
NOVEMBER 05
* Post 1
* Post 2
* Post 3
NOVEMBER 05
* Post 1
* Post 2
* Post 3

NOVEMBER 04
* Post 1
* Post 2

NOVEMBER 04
* Post 1
* Post 2
```

Please help me!

Here's my code:

```
      <?php
    include("db.php");
    include("function.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"select distinct post_submitted_on from posts order by id desc");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $datetime=$row['post_submitted_on']; //2016-11-05 23:10:45
    $date=date("d",strtotime($datetime)); //05
    $month=date("F",strtotime($datetime)); //November
    $final_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($datetime)); //2016-11-05
  ?>
      <h4 class="date">
        <i style="vertical-align: baseline;" class="fa fa-calendar-o date"></i> <B class="date">TODAY, <?php echo strtoupper($month);?> <?php echo ordinal("$date");?></B> <!-- prints TODAY, NOVEMBER 05 -->
      </h4>
      <?php
        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select distinct * from posts where post_date='$final_date' order by id desc"); //selecting all posts based on the current date and load all past entries based on past date
        while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
      ?>
      <table width="100%" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php echo $r['title'];?>
            <?php echo $r['url'];?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Add a GROUP BY.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you :) your suggestion worked!

Comment: I posted a community wiki answer below that you can mark off as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just post this as a community wiki since it was mentioned by myself in comments and being the solution to this question.

- Add a `GROUP BY col` to your query, since using DISTINCT doesn't always do the job.

Consult the following Q&A on Stack about this type of behaviour:

- [Why my mysql DISTINCT doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534379/why-my-mysql-distinct-doesnt-work)
- [MySQL select distinct doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337536/mysql-select-distinct-doesnt-work)
  -